# Active Record search in Ruby for certain text pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say, I have class Person with a field 'full_name'. How can I find all records where this field includes pattern 'smith'?

Comment: People search in DB with SQL, not with AR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Sql `like` or `ilike` queries

**Edit** as per @Vaibhav Kaushal comment

```
Person.where("full_name LIKE ?", "'%smith%'")
```

For **MySQL** database,

```
Person.where("full_name  RLIKE ?", 'smith')
```

If you want to use `OR` i.e. find Person objects having full_name matching 'smith', 'roger' or 'dwane', you can use below,

```
Person.where("full_name  RLIKE ?", 'smith | roger | dwane')
```

Comment: A better version is: `People.where("full_name LIKE ?", "'%smith%'")`

Comment: Use `Person` instead of `People` as singular form for model name. +1